# How to make Decimal conform LosslessStringConvertible in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, decimal, extension-methods

I want to convert Decimal to String in Swift 5.

Since I directly tried

```
String(aDecimalNumber)
```

Then Xcode gives error message saying:

> **Decimal needs to conform LosslessStringConvertible**

so I add an extension looks like:

```
extension Decimal: LosslessStringConvertible {
    public init?(_ description: String) {


    }
}
```

But it won't work. My understanding is to extract the description, which is of String type, to a Decimal. But not sure how to do this?

Comment: *“It says Decimal needs to conform LosslessStringConvertible”* – please post the exact code which produces this error message. You don't need LosslessStringConvertible conformance to convert a Decimal to a String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation:

```
extension Decimal: LosslessStringConvertible {
    public init?(_ description: String) {
        guard let decimal = Decimal(string: description) else {
            return nil
        }
        self = decimal
    }
}


let d: Decimal? = Decimal("1e9")  //1000000000
```

Comment: Is that okay to directly call `String(describing: decimalNumber) ` without the extension?

Comment: @JINGYAHAN It is always possible to do: `let d = Decimal(string: "1e9")!` and get the string description using `String(describing: d)` or `d.description`